# Creating a SQL Server stored procedure in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

How to create a SQL Server stored procedure in VB.NET by using `Imports System.Data.SqlClient`?

```
Public Function createstbkdb()
    Return "CREATE PROCEDURE test4444 " + _
            +"AS" + _
            +"GO"
End Function
```

Regards,

Comment: Execute `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement directly against the database via SSMS. If what you're showing here is the full text of what you're attempting to execute, it's invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)(), passing in the text of your procedure (as queryString in the linked MSDN example).

Note that the connection executing the VB.NET code must have appropriate permissions in the database to create the procedure.

**UPDATE**

As @CmlJame noted, leave out the "GO".  That is meaningful to SSMS but should not be included in the call to ExecuteNonQuery().

Comment: I have tried with ExecuteNonQuery already, but it still show Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.

Comment: Conversion from string "CREATE PROCEDURE test4444" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: @CmlJame `GO` is not a T-SQL keyword - it is a batch separator in client tools like Management Studio. You shouldn't be sending `GO` from your program (and I question whether you really should be creating procedures from your program, either).